# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium 2.33 (Python) with Firefox 16 in linux
For every script I get firefox profile and then webdriver. It works but except for one scenario I get this error
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException

If I run script after another immediately I get above error otherwise it is fine. Is there a solution to my problem. If I give 4-5 mins gap it works.

Comment: do you call `driver.close()` after your test is done?